# problem with QuickTime dmuxer in Totem player (.mp4 and .mov files)

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, multimedia, totem

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and install ubuntu-restricted-extras but Totem player still unable to play .mp4 and .mov files it also search for suitable plugins and no packages found.

VLC media player can play these files but i want Totem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10/+bug/856988

Worked for me